# How to switch UITabBars as a result of UIButton segue?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

I have a UITabBar that currently has 4 tabs and it works great. I need to navigate to a new set of tabs as if the app was entering a different mode. Pushing the new UITabBar via the navigationController doesn't work – it currently just adds a new UITabBar on top of the old one and adds a new `UINavigationBar` under the old one. Would I create a whole new UIWindow whose rootViewController is my new `UITabBarController`?

```
@objc func startSecondStory() {
    let newTabs = SecondaryTabBarController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(newTabs, animated: true)
}
```

The code is the action of a pushed UIButton. I don't want the new UITabBar to be pushed on top of the stack. I'd prefer it just took as a whole new UINavigationController with the rootView as SecondaryTabBarController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ( this will clear previous one)

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([newTabs],animated:true)
```

//

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = newTabs
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it creates a UINavigationController and UITabBar inside the view of the old ones. Its the same issue as using pushViewController(_:animated:).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I could just use present(_:animated:completion:). However, I would still like to know if there is a more efficient way to do this to reduce memory usage. I think this just pops the new UITabBarController on top of the stack without removing the old one.